# Typescript constructor with @injectable and normal param

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to do this:

```js
export class TypedService {
    protected baseUrl: string;

    constructor(section: string, protected http: HttpClient) {
        this.baseUrl = `${environment.apiUri}/${section}`;
    }
```

where the intent is the subclass will call the constructor and pass in the `section` to se the `baseUrl`.  However, doing it like this fails because it wants the subclass to also pass the `http` parameter.

Is it possible for the base class to inject a value like this but still have the subclass pass a value?

Comment: You would usually inject an injectable into another class' constructor instead of creating a `new` instance yourself, so this is not how you would design it

Comment: :(  It's a shame that every subclass has to do the injection vs. just being able to do it in the base class.